# Is there a possibility to have multiple agenda views open at once?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have a custom agenda view which shows the Items I did last week and the items I have to do in this week. This view is based on a filter of TODO items. However, it would be good to see scheduled items and deadlines in another buffer.

Of course I could open another emacs instance and open there a different agenda, but is there another way so that I can examine two different agenda views within the same frame, but in different buffers?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but org-mode *is* designed to have multiple views in *the same* buffer -- one particular view, followed by the next (with a divider `======`).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `org-agenda-sticky`.

See the [Org-Manual - Agenda Dispatcher](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-dispatcher.html) for details.

> `*` ::
>   Toggle sticky agenda views. By default, Org maintains only a single agenda buffer
>   and rebuilds it each time you change the view, to
>   make sure everything is always up to date. If you switch between views
>   often and the build time bothers you, you can turn on sticky agenda
>   buffers (make this the default by customizing the variable
>   `org-agenda-sticky`). With sticky agendas, the dispatcher only switches
>   to the selected view, you need to update it by hand with `r` or `g`. You
>   can toggle sticky agenda view any time with `org-toggle-sticky-agenda`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this could give you what you're looking for:

1. Open an agenda view
2. Run `M-x rename-uniquely` or `M-x rename-buffer`
3. Open another agenda view

Comment: This works for creating two views, but I could not update the renamed buffer. If I press "r" in the renamed agenda buffer a new agenda window is opened, which is named like the default agenda. Is there a way to update the renamed agena?